# When to use constinit and consteval?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20, consteval, constinit

The usage of `constexpr` is quite straightforward which is to make sure the code can be evaluated at the compile time itself.

But the latest features of C++ 20 which provides `constinit` and `consteval` are little bit confusing. Can someone provide the practical use case of `constinit` and `consteval`?

Comment: Constinit can help to avoid the static initialization fiasco - it enforces that initalization happens at compile time rather at runtime.
But to use constinit the type must have a constexpr constructor which is of course not the case for all types.